# lwjgl 2d rendering conflict between two tetxures

Tags: java, opengl, textures, rendering, lwjgl

Ok so I am currently working on a 2d game in java with LWJGL. I have a fairly solid understanding of java and how it works and know the basics of how games work and LWJGL/openGL, but I am having this really weird issue with rendering textures. I determined that one of my draw methods here is the culprit ..

```
public static void texturedTriangleInverted(float x, float y, float width, float height, Texture texture) {
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
        {

            GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
            texture.bind();

            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
                {
                    GL11.glVertex2f(width / 2, 0);
                    GL11.glTexCoord2f(width / 2, 0);

                    GL11.glVertex2f(0, height);
                    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);

                    GL11.glVertex2f(width, height);
                    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                }
            GL11.glEnd();
        }
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

so what happens is if I render anything with this method the next thing rendered looks like it literally was compressed on one end and stretched on the other, even if the next thing rendered is not rendered with this method. I am almost positive that it has to do with the argument I passed into the `Gl11.glTexCoord2f(float x, float y)` methods, but I cant figure out how to fix it.

here is my openGL initialization code

```
private void initGL() {
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, Strings.DISPLAY_WIDTH, 0, Strings.DISPLAY_HEIGHT, -1, 1);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D);
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Strings.DISPLAY_WIDTH, Strings.DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 0);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}
```

my game loop code

```
    private void gameLoop() {
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glTranslatef(Strings.transX, Strings.transY, 0);

        this.level.update();
        this.level.render();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(Strings.FPS_CAP);
    }

    Keyboard.destroy();
    Display.destroy();

}
```

my texture loading code (note I used slick to load my textures)

```
public static final Texture loadTexture(String location) {
    try {
        if (textureExists(location)) {
            return TextureLoader.getTexture("png", new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(location))), false);
        } else {
            System.err.println("txture does not exist");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your `glTexCoord` before the `glVertex` it refers to, not after. This is the same as with `glColor` and `glNormal`, `glVertex` uses the last attributes that you set.

Comment: thank you very much I changed that in all my rendering methods and it works perfectly now :)